# Change Contents of <li> Using jQueryUI Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable, replacewith

I have tried many things but here are my most recent attempts. I just want to change the < li > contents upon dropping the < li > onto the "#added" < div >. I am using a 'switch' statement to change each element separately. I have tried using .remove() as well as [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), I am new to jQuery so if you know a better way I would be happy to hear it. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoderLevel1/h56y8t39/3/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var dHtml = "";
    var icons = [];

    var fieldTypes = [{
            "label": "Text",
            "icon": "abc-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_text",
            "type": "<input type='text' disabled/>"
        }, {
            "label": "Date",
            "icon": "calendar-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_date",
            "type": "<input type='date' disabled/>"
        }, {
            "label": "Radio",
            "icon": "radio-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_radio",
            "type": "<input type='radio' disabled/>"
        }, {
            "label": "Checkbox",
            "icon": "checkbox-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_checkbox",
            "type": "<input type='checkbox' disabled/>"
        }, {
            "label": "Selector",
            "icon": "dropdown-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_selector",
            "type": "<input type='text' disabled/>"
        }, {
            "label": "Telephone",
            "icon": "telephone-icon",
            "cls": "btntype_telephone",
            "type": "<input type='tel' disabled/>"
        }];

    for (var f = 0; f < fieldTypes.length; f++) {
        var field = fieldTypes[f];
        dHtml += "<li style='list-style:none;' class='draggable-source " + field.cls + "'><div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' class='drag' id='drag'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div><p style='margin-top:12px'>" + field.label + "</p></div></li>";
    };

    // DRAGGABLE AND SORTABLE

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("li").each(function () {
            jQuery(this).draggable({
                helper: "clone"
            });
        });

        jQuery("#added").droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var draggedElement = ui.draggable;

                var classList = draggedElement[0].className.split(/\s+/);
                var fieldClass = "btntype_text";
                for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
                    if (classList[i].substr(0, 8) === "btntype_") {
                        fieldClass = classList[i];
                    }

                }
                console.log(fieldClass);

                switch (fieldClass) {
                    //Nothing Changes
                    case 'btntype_text':
                        jQuery("div.added.li.btntype_text.div.drag").replaceWith("<div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' id='dropBg'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div></div>");
                        break;
                        //Nothing Changes
                    case 'btntype_checkbox':
                        jQuery("div.added.li.btntype_text.div").remove();
                        break;
                        //Nothing Changes
                    case 'btntype_radio':
                        jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().replaceWith("<li style='list-style:none;' class='draggable-source " + field.cls + "'><div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' id='dropBg'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div></div></li>");
                        break;
                        //Nothing Changes
                    case 'btntype_date':
                        jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().replaceWith("<div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' id='dropBg'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div></div>");
                        break;
                        //Added div Disappears
                    default:
                        jQuery(this).remove();
                        jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this).replaceWith("<li style='list-style:none;' class='draggable-source " + field.cls + "'><div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' id='dropBg'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div></div></li>");
                }


                console.log(draggedElement.attr('class'));
                var targetElem = jQuery(this).attr("id");

                jQuery(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                if (jQuery(ui.draggable).hasClass('draggable-source')) jQuery(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo(this).removeClass('draggable-source');
                else jQuery(ui.draggable).appendTo(this);

                console.log(this.id);

            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function () {
                jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery('#pop').html(dHtml);

    console.log(dHtml);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

`jQuery("div.added.li.btntype_text.div.drag")` - this would never work. `added` is an id and not a class (so use `#`). Also `div` is not a class and you should be using some spaces there instead of dots. JQuery selectors work like CSS selectors.

You may want to use a `switch` if you want to do specific things for different elements dropped. Otherwise you may just use dynamic selectors, like so:
`$('#added .' + fieldClass)`

I have updated your fiddle. Fixed the selector and used `html()` function to replace content. I also had to slightly delay it (`setTimeout`) as your loop takes a bit of time to finish (try without it and it won't work on first attempt).

Anyways, here's the fiddle (only first case in switch statement is fixed, so it will only work for the "Text" element. Put it outside of `switch` and it will work for all.

Code added:

```
case 'btntype_text':               
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#added .' + fieldClass).html("<div style='margin-top:6px; margin-right:5px;' id='dropBg'><div style='float:left; margin-top:6px;' id='" + field.icon + "'></div></div>");
    }, 100);                   
break;
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/h56y8t39/6/

Comment: Thanks for the setTimout insight. I would have not known to use that.